# No return type needed for array in C++?

Tags: c++, scope, return

I am a novice C++ user with experience in Python. I was practicing some sorting algorithms and noticed that in C++, you don't have to return array types after they have went through a sorting function. In my code below `arr` is sorted correctly when passed to `selectionSort`. What confuses me, is that this works without a return. I could have sworn objects are destroyed within local scopes when the compilers hits the closing bracket of the function.

Could someone explain this to me?

```
void selectionSort(int arr[], int n){

int i, j, temp, min;

for (i = 0; i< n - 1; i++){
    min = i;
    for (j = i+1; j < n; j++){
        if(arr[j] < arr[min]){
            min = j;
        }
        temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[min];
        arr[min] = temp;
    }
}

}

int main(){

int nums[] = {4,5,7,3};
int n = sizeof(nums)/sizeof(int);

selectionSort(nums, n);

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    cout << nums[i] << endl;
}
```

output: 3,4,5,7

Comment: Because C-style arrays are passed by reference

Comment: @ArdentCoder not quite correct. I think I know what you mean but passing a pointer and passing a reference is not the same

Comment: @idclev463035818 English is my third language lol, but I hope you got what I meant :P Should I delete it?

Comment: @idclev463035818 Somebody upvoted the question after it got closed, so couldn't it be answered?

Comment: Nothing much wrong with this question other than it having been asked and answered on many occasions. Leave it for the automated clean-up scripts would be my call. I dislike the terminology problem we have in C++ with passing by reference. The proper terminology would be "Arrays [decay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying) to pointers."

Comment: @ArdentCoder Arrays have distinct types from pointers, but they decay to pointers at the slightest touch. Passing a reference to an array would look like this `void selectionSort(int (&arr)[4]){...}`

Comment: @alterigel Wow, that's new to me. I think I should have said "passed by address"?

Comment: @ArdentCoder You can have pointers to arrays too :-) `int (*pointerToArray)[4] = &nums;` Like I said, arrays are distinct types. But the size is fixed in the array type, so this isn't useful if you want variable-sized arrays. That's why C programmers use simple pointers and length. C++ programs use things like `std::vector`, `std::array`, `std::span`, etc.

Comment: Hey guys, yes I think I have my answer. When an array is passed to a function, it decays to a pointer unlike with an int. Also explains why the `sizeof` of my array changed from `main` to `selectionSort` :p

Comment: @neerbasu Yes, that's it. I'll give you +10, because I never liked my questions getting closed but you took it in the spirit and followed the link to get your answer :)